# Why it's not possible to use any magic constants in a static context?

Tags: php, object, static

Is there any particular reason to deny the use of magic constants (like `__DIR__`) in PHP when in a static context? OOP POV seems nothing is wrong since `__DIR__` is "global" that is not instance specific:

```
class MyClass
{

    protected static $options = array(
            'key1' => 2,
            'key2' => __DIR__ .'/mypic.png' // Triggers a syntax error
    );

    public function __construct() {}

}
```

**EDIT** clarification about the question. I'm interested in "why" it's not possible. For example, speaking about static stuff, anyone knows this is not possible:

```
public static function getName() { return $this->name; }
```

because `getName()` is shared across multiple instances and `$this->name` doesn't make any sense because static function "doesn't know" what instance to refer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't the use of `__DIR__` or magic constants specifically here that isn't permissible. It is the dynamic construction of anything inside a property definition that isn't allowed. You'd also get a syntax error if you tried to concatenate two atomic strings like `"a" . "b"` inside a static property definition.

[From the docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.... And concatenation, even onto a constant, counts as an expression which isn't allowed.

The PHP manual doesn't specify why initializing static variables with the result of an expression is a parse error, but it is likely due to the fact that [static declarations are resolved at compile time](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), not runtime.

Comment: Thanks, so good to know, but it really doesn't answer the actual question, that is why it's not (say "physically") possible.

Comment: Probably because the init values are decided at compile time (yes, PHP is compiled into opcodes for the Zend engine), not run time.

Comment: @Gremo See my addition. Though it isn't explicitly stated in the manual as the reason, I believe it's because static properties are resolved at compile time not runtime.

Comment: @Gremo The answer may not be accurate to your question but it is practically useful.

Comment: The same *no-expression* restriction applies to instance properties and `const`s, too.